# How to restart Mongodb server with replcaition in azure?

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-virtual-machine, bitnami, mongodb-replica-set

I'm using **MongoDB with replication(Bitnami)** on Azure and I have attached an SSD premium disk and mounted on MongoDB VM.
Do I need to restart a MongoDB server? if yes then how to restart MongoDB server.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you need restart your MongoDB restart.

Please refer to this [official document](https://docs.bitnami.com/azure-templates/infrastructure/mongodb/). You could restart Mongodb with following command.

```
sudo service bitnami restart
```

You could use `sudo service bitnami status` to check your Mongodb status. Here is the result.

```
bitnami@shuitest0:~$ sudo service bitnami status
● bitnami.service - LSB: Bitnami Init Script
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/bitnami)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-08-03 08:36:58 UTC; 8min ago
  Process: 14359 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/bitnami start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bitnami.service
           ├─14395 /opt/bitnami/mongodb/bin/mongod --config /opt/bitnami/mongodb/conf/mongodb.conf
           └─14479 /opt/bitnami/gonit/gonit-linux-x64.run
```

Note: Bitnami series products usually use this method to restart service.

Comment: This [link](https://community.bitnami.com/t/mongodb-replica-set-on-azure/45126/2) also solves your question.

Comment: Thank you, @walter.